# scalajs Diode failing to re-render React components on state change?

Tags: scala, reactjs, scala.js, diode

EDIT: I'm a dolt who was using an outdated version of Diode. Upgrading to the 1.0 release resolved the issue.

I have a Scalajs/Diode/React system set up, and in one section I've run into some (lack of) behavior that has me stumped. I am under the impression that when you connect a React component into the Diode state via a line like the following:

`val ChangeClassButton = SelectCircuit.connect(_.selection)(p => DiodeChangeClassButton(p))`

that the ChangeClassButton should re-render whenever `selection` is updated in the Diode circuit.

I have verified that the Diode event dispatch and state updates seem to be working as intended, but the React components `connect`ed into `selection` are not re-rendering when `selection` changes. Other components attached to other portions of the Circuit state are re-rendering as expected upon pertinent state changes.

Here is the React component that should be re-rendering:

```
val DiodeChangeClassButton = ReactComponentB[ModelProxy[String]]("SaveButton")
    .render_P { case proxy =>
      println("Rendering ChangeClassButton and selection is: " + proxy.value)
      if(proxy.value != "")
        <.div(
          ^.cursor := "pointer",
          ^.onClick --> proxy.dispatch(ChangeClass(proxy.value)),
          "String is: " + proxy.value
        )
      else
        <.div()
  }.build
  val ChangeClassButton = SelectCircuit.connect(_.selection)(p => DiodeChangeClassButton(p))
```

Here is the component that dispatches the Diode action which changes `selection`:

```
val DiodeClassificationBox = ReactComponentB[ModelProxy[Pot[PaperInfoShort]]]("ClassBox")
    .render_P { case proxy =>
      println("ClassificationBox is rendering")
      <.div(
        TitleBar("Classification"),
        ReadOnlyInputBar(proxy.value.get.mrPrim),
        <.div(
          ^.onMouseUp --> proxy.dispatch(HighlightChange),
          ReadOnlyInputBar((for(s <- proxy.value.get.secondaries) yield s.classCode).mkString(" "))
        )
      )
  }.build
  val ClassificationBox = SelectCircuit.connect(_.paperInfo)(p => DiodeClassificationBox(p))
```

And here is the action handler in SelectCircuit:

```
class HighlightHandler[M](modelRW: ModelRW[M, String]) extends ActionHandler(modelRW)
{
    override def handle =
      {
        case InitSelection =>
          updated("")
        case HighlightChange =>
          if (checkClasses(dom.window.getSelection().toString))
            updated(dom.window.getSelection().toString)
          else
            updated("")
      }
}
```

Am I wrong in expected React Components connected into _.selection to re-render whenever `updated()` is called here? I am fairly new to Diode and React, so I might be misunderstanding under what circumstances that happens.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To me it looks like you're doing it correctly, so the problem may lie somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Seems likely, but I'm at a loss for where else the problem could be. Currently doing some refactoring in the hopes of the miracle fix.